# How to use a string' value as an object name?

Tags: swift

I have many objects and I need to use one of them depending on whatever the user pressed to fill my table view. for reducing the use of if statements I think that maybe storing the name of the needed object on a string variable will help. and when the need of filling the table view the string variable will be used instead of check which the approbate object name.

```
// objects defined here from different classes.

    var currentSection : String 

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 { //
            currentSection = "object1"
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2 { //
            currentSection = "object2"
        }
        .........etc 
    }

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

       return(currentSection.item.count) 
}
```

this is what I had done but it didn't work, error: "Value of type 'String' has no member 'item'"

anyone please telling me how to tell the compiler to use the string' value as an object name?

Comment: I would use an enum that returns objects for names.

Comment: Short answer: You can't do that.

Comment: Change the declaration of `currentSection` from `String` to whatever `object1` and `object2` are. Then assign a reference to the object instead of  the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `currentSection` is a string, it doesn't know anything about objects, so `currentSection.item` is meaningless. Instead, what you could do is use a [dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) that associates string *keys* to *values* that represent the data in your section.

```
struct RowItem {} // the thing that represents the text for your table view row

class MyViewController {
  var sectionData: [String: [RowItem]] = [:]  // a dictionary that associates string keys to arrays of RowItem
  var currentSection: String = ""

  func tableView(_ tableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let thisSection = sectionData[currentSection] ?? [] // you might not have data in the dictionary for currentSection
    return thisSection.count
  }
}
```

#### Update

What is the type that you are using to back your table view cells? In `cellForRow` you have to configure a cell with some text, images, etc. — whatever the type is of the object that you're using for this (I used `RowItem` above) should be the type in your dictionary -- `[String: [MyRowTypeWhateverThatIs]]`. So each string **key** maps to a **value** that's an **array of data.** The items in this array will correspond to the cells in your table view.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dataForKey: [RowItemOrWhatever] = sectionData[currentSection] ?? []  // this array contains items that correspond 1:1 to the cells in your table view
    if indexPath.row >= dataForKey.count { return UITableViewCell() } // it's possible that this index could be outside the bounds of dataForKey, so we need to handle that case sensibly

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reusableCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    let item = dataForKey[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.text    // or whatever it is that you're doing with these pieces of data
    return cell
  }
```

That way you can use the count of the array in `numberOfRows` and index into the array to get the value for a specific row in `cellForRow`. As far as IndexPath goes, you only want to use that to index into your own data in cellForRow -- you shouldn't need to store index paths. You will want to define `RowItem` in such a way that it will have the data you need to configure your cell. So if my cell has some main text, some detail text, and an image, i would define `RowItem` like this:

```
struct RowItem {
  var mainText: String
  var detailText: String
  var image: UIImage
}
```

Comment: `= ""` that's very sketchy.

Comment: It's either that or make `currentSection` optional. I don't see how it makes a difference in this context.

Comment: @jefflovejapan Sorry I didn't get the idea. I am a beginner and what I know about dictionary is simple. Could you explain more about struct RowItem {} in your code?

Comment: I tried to define a dictionary of [String : AnyObject] but I got error "AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSIndexPath'" at this line: let p = currentObject.item[indexPath.row]